# Error using Solve on Matrix Multiplication

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, warning-messages

I am trying to make a function the will find that value of $x$ in the following equation:
$x.a=b$

all values of $x, a, b$ are matrices. The dimensions of $x$ are unknown, but $a$ and $b$ have the same dimensions of $n*8$ where $n$ depends on the matrix used in the function

I am to understand that the dimensions of $x$ are going to be $n*n$ so that the shapes of the matrix are compatible in the equation.

The functions arguments are simply $a$ and $b$, and I tried setting it up as follows:

```
GetValueOfX[a_,b_] := Solve[x.a==b,x]
```

But when I try put in values for $a$ and $b$, I get the following error:

```
Solve::nsmet : This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

I am very confused by this, is it telling me there are an infinite number of outcomes (I googled the error and this was a common cause) or is this kind of Matrix Multiplication incompatible with Solve as it does not know the dimensions of $x$. And more importantly, is there always going to be an answer?

The values I tested were:

$a=\begin{matrix}116&101&115&116&105&110&103&44\\32&116&101&115&116&105&110&103\end{matrix}$

$b=\begin{matrix}114&117&110&110&105&110&103&44\\32&114&117&110&110&105&110&103\end{matrix}$

P.S. if you want to know, those matrices are the character codes of a phrase and that is how I got them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to solve $A x=b$ for $x$.

The dimensions of $x$ is not unknown, clearly it is known, since the inner dimensions must match between $A$ and $x$ and the outer dimension must match with $b$. Any way, may be you can look at [LinearSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html)

```
n = 2;
a = Table[RandomReal[1], {n}, {8}];
b = Table[RandomReal[1], {n}, {8}];
(x = LinearSolve[a, b]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above does `mldivide` which is in Matlab written as `A\B`, to do `mrdivide` which is `B/A`, then these are related by `B/A=(A'\B')'` hence

```
n = 2;
a = Table[RandomReal[1], {n}, {8}];
b = Table[RandomReal[1], {n}, {8}];
x = ConjugateTranspose[LeastSquares[Transpose[a], Transpose[b]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Dimensions matches ok.  `xA=B` since $A$ is $2 \times 8$ and $B$ is $2 \times 8$ then $x$ is $2 \times 2$

Comment: but how can i do $x.a=b$, this only shows $a.x=b$ and matrix multiplication is not commutative so it isn't the same

Comment: @user9053 so, you are then trying to do mrdivide and not mldivide? if so, please see update.

Comment: I tried using the updated mrdivide bit, but when substituting it back into the equation $x.a=b$, I got a different result for $b$ so it doesn't work

Comment: @user9053 it is using least squares solution. We are using random numbers. But you have above Ax=b and xA=B definitions that I know about. Well, this is the limit of my linear algebra skills. If I think of something else will add.

Comment: Thanks for your help, hopefully someone else finds a solution. When putting //N at the end of the equation however, the final answer was about 0-10 off each value, so its close but no cigar

Answer (score 0):

Your no of unknown = n^2;
Your no of equation = 8n;

So you can only get a unique solution for your system when n^2=8n.
So only for n=8 its possible to get a unique solution.

This is just to show that your system of equation is not solvable for n=2(or any other integer excluding 8)

```
n = 2;
a = {{116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103, 44}, {32, 116, 101, 115, 116,
 105, 110, 103}};
b = {{114, 117, 110, 110, 105, 110, 103, 44}, {32, 114, 117, 110, 110,
 105, 110, 103}};
```

(* Create array containing   elements of the square matrix x and the array eq for L.H.S 
    of x.a=b  *)

```
 Array[x, {n, n}]; Array[eq, {n,8}];
```

(* index list for summing up in the matrix multiplication*)

```
 list = Table[{j}, {j, 1, n}];
```

(* List of index of all elements in x *)

```
 slist = Partition[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]], 2];
 varList = x[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ slist
```

(* Equates the ij th element of L.H.S to R.H.S*)

```
 eq[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{}, 
 b[[i, j]] - Total[x[i, #[[1]]]*a[[#[[1]], j]] & /@ list] == 0]
```

(* index list for all the n * 8 equations*)

```
list1 = Partition[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 8}]], 2];
eqList = eq[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ list1(* list of all equations*)
```

The output gives you 16 equations.

```
partialsolutionPossible[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := 
Solve[{eqList[[n1]], eqList[[n2]], eqList[[n3]], eqList[[n4]]}, 
 varList]
(* This gives the possible solutions for four equations chosen at a
time n1 and n2 has to be between 1 & 8 n3 and n4 is between 9 & 16 *)

 partialsolutionPossible[1, 2, 9, 10]
   (* This is not the solution for  the fullsystem because you cannot   
    simultaneously satisfy all 16 together*)
```

{{x[1, 1] -> 395/426, x[1, 2] -> 343/1704, x[2, 1] -> 4/639, 
  x[2, 2] -> 1249/1278}}

Comment: why is that, are you saying that if n is 3 that there are multiple solutions for the 3*3 matrix which is $x$

Keep in mind that a 3*3 matrix by a 3*8 matrix returns a 3*8 matrix.

Comment: If x is 3*3 matrix then it has 9 elements.So solving x implies finding the value of those 9 unknowns.So for n=3 x.a will give 3*8 matrix containing 24 elements with where each one of them is some linear combination of those 9 unknowns.Now you equate these 24 equations to the corresponding one on R.H.S.Basically u will end up with 24 equation in 9 unknowns which is called an overdetermined system. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)

Comment: ok, so lets say I want to stick to this overdetermined system, how do I find one of the possible solutions that exist? All I need is one example for what I am trying to achieve, or are you saying that there is no solution at all?

Comment: Yes im saying that there is no solution in that case.have a look at the case for n=2.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try and make $a$ and $b$ square matrices for this to work then